# Can't upgrade from terraform version 0.13 to 0.14 - Error: Invalid legacy provider address

Tags: terraform, upgrade, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to upgrade my terraform version from 0.13.7 to 0.14 but get this error when moving to version 0.14:

```
Error: Invalid legacy provider address

This configuration or its associated state refers to the unqualified provider
"aws".

You must complete the Terraform 0.13 upgrade process before upgrading to later
versions.

Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried everything i can find online about this error. I have done:

- Ran terraform init and apply using terraform v13 successfully
- ran the "terraform 0.13upgrade" command on my .tf files
- made sure all modules (even modules within modules etc) have also had the "terraform 0.13upgrade" command ran
- Ran this command  `terraform state replace-provider "registry.terraform.io/-/aws" "hashicorp/aws"`
- Double checked the state file and confirmed there is no "registry.terraform.io/-/aws" that exists
- Ran terraform init -upgrade
- Remove aws provider version constraints incase there were any old versions that aren't compatible with TF v13
- Re-ran terraform on 0.13.0 and applied (to see if the version of 13 i used mattered)

What else is the issue? What else can I try?

UPDATE: my required providers block:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    archive = {
      source = "hashicorp/archive"
    }
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
    template = {
      source = "hashicorp/template"
    }
    vault = {
      source = "hashicorp/vault"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `required_providers` block(s).

Comment: @MattSchuchard updated my question to add my required providers block. When i try to move to version 14 all i do is change "required_version = ">= 0.13"" to "required_version = ">= 0.14""

Comment: I wonder if you have the same problem if you use `required_version = "~> 0.13"` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/versions but outside of that it's possible some syntax issues were missed during the upgrade. I would check the modules & check for how data sources or other modules are referenced. I would also check any functions / how they're used & compare with terraform docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063726/terraform-upgrade-to-0-15-getting-invalid-legacy-provider-address-for-provide)

TL;DR - Have to select workspace in the terraform init command.